# get all post that belong to one user

Tags: mysql, node.js, join

i want to join two table in mysql node js. example POST and Users table. i want to get all post that belong to one user.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM POST
INNER JOIN Users ON POST.user = Users.user;
```

this above code will combine the 2 tables which has the same user in both tables

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your problem, you want to join two table where a value correspond. The solution for that would be to use a JOIN clause.

Let's make an example,

Here's my table1:

| id | firstname |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Alex |
| 2 | John |

Here's my table2:

| id | lastname |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Brown |
| 2 | Davis |

So here what I want is to get the full name of a user by their id, in this case I would do:

```
SELECT table1.firstname, table2.lastname FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id
```

`SELECT` the values I want but I add the table name infront of the value
`FROM` the first table I want to join `INNNER JOIN` the second table I want to join
`ON` the table1.value that correspond to table2.value

And this would be my result:

| id | firstname | lastname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alex | Brown |
| 2 | John | Davis |

I hope that you understand what todo, it's the first time I help someone here and I'm not really sure if I did good but I think it will still help you.

If you want more information about JOIN clause:
Source: [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Comment: thanks for your answer but my question is to get all post that login user.mean his on Post